# Inactive window -Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

As new to tkinter, I am working on an **application** in which pressing f5 refreshes the page of chrome. Instead of using pyautogui (which is very weird) to change the tab from application to chrome and then press F5. *I need to know that is there a way that if chrome is active and application is in-active and by pressing the button on the app will stay make the chrome active and perform f5(refreshing)?*

**here is my code:**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import pyautogui as pg

def F5(event):
    
    pg.hotkey('f5')
    print('pressed f5')
   

root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes("-topmost", True)
root.attributes("-alpha", 0.3)
root.overrideredirect(True)

button = ttk.Button(root, text = 'F5',state='active')

button.bind('<Button-1>',F5)
button.pack(side = tk.TOP)


root.geometry('+1+78')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: As on-screen keyboard of windows when pressed f5 refreshes page but it is inactive if you notice but tkinter app gets active and presses f5 in the app himself

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pyautogui.getWindowsWithTitle()` to locate and activate the chrome window:

```py
def F5(event):
    # locate chrome windows
    windows = pg.getWindowsWithTitle('google chrome')
    if windows:
        # chrome windows found, activate the first one
        windows[0].activate()
        # send F5 key to active window
        pg.hotkey('f5')
        print('pressed f5')
```